# input type = text not displaying in chrome properly

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have an input field generated by Microsoft MVC. It is later edited by different scripts. Everything is displayed properly in IE, but in chrome the browser behaves as if the value was not set. HTML:

```html
<input name="name[id]" id="name[id]" value="0,00" type="text" readonly="" class="input-block-level validate[required] text-input">
```

What I mean by that is that I get a blank input field.

Interestingly, when I run the following script from chrome console, everything displays properly:

```
$("[id^=name[").each(function () {
    this.value = this.getAttribute("value");
})
```

At the same time, this script does not repair the problem if I run it from a .js file loaded by the web page.

EDIT:
Some more info, if I type `$0.value` in chrome console, i get `""`, but if I type `$0.getAttribute("value")` the output is `0,00` (what I want)

Comment: What does the Chrome developer console show you about the element?

Comment: Why does the element have a `name` and `id` that contains `[` and `]` characters?

Comment: @ScottMarcus because other developers set it up thaw way a few years ago

Comment: @Pointy if you are asking me what is displayed if i type $0 in the console after clicking on the element, i get `<input name="name[id]" id="name[id]" value="0,00" type="text" readonly class="input-block-level validate[required] text-input">` , if that's not what you were asking for, please specify

Comment: Not related, but please stop using `$(this)[0]` and use `this`... It makes me wanna cry every time I see it

Comment: @UlysseBN Not making a stranger cry on the internet shall be my good deed of the day

Comment: I ran the code snippet above in chrome and I see the value "0,00" in the text field. Do you use the latest chrome version?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant; the idea was to verify that the element is in the DOM the way your source code expects. And it seems to be; it's not clear why you wouldn't see the value in the field. It's *possible* that some CSS is messing things up of course.

Comment: @Pointy but then why would my javascript console call solve the problem?

Comment: Good point. I can't think of anything other than that though; I've never seen Chrome refuse to pay attention to a "value" attribute.